# Manually Position Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I'm trying to create a customized dialog for my applications. Its kinda like windows 8 style, simple plain rectangle using all screen width and stuff. I know this is done by themes and styles but **my problem is:**

I don't want it to be vertically centered. I want to be able to move it up and down as I wish. I have thought of using a vertical linear layout with 3 other layouts in it: Top, middle, bottom. And then set the Top and Bottom ones' backgrounds to transparent which leaves the middle one as my practical activity layout.
However, this seems very twisty for me. Is there a more intuitive way to do it?

another question though. Is it possible for Microsoft to sue me for this? [I'm not an expert in those legal issues]